# MYSQL slow queries in "slow queries log" - but same queries runs very fast manually

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

as title states, in my database various queries appear in the slow queries log, but when I run them manually they run 10x faster.

for example a relatively simple select query with several order by params takes often up to 100 seconds in log(yes table is very big)... but when I run it myself on the same DB it takes 2 seconds or so.

I've examined the server's performance and there doesn't seem to be a particular slowdown or bottleneck at the time, nor are many queries taking long time at that period but just the one.

how can I begin to analyze such a problem?

thanks for the help

Comment: I'd start by posting one of such queries here for assistance in analyzing it along with an "EXPLAIN SELECT ..." to show what the engine wants to do for its query execution path.

Comment: Usually if a query takes 1 or more seconds its captured by slow query log. 2 seconds is certainly higher than 1 second.

Comment: Wild guess: The query is fast when you run it manually because the results were cached during the first execution of the query. To check it out, clear all caches and then try the same query again - it should take 100 seconds.

Comment: You might also try asking at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

Your system may have been more busy when the offending query entered the slow log.

The slow log may indicate that indexes aren't being fully utilized if the rows_examined is larger than the result set. Therefore, the execution time should be considered a clue that a query has a problem, but the rows_examined will give you more of a definitive answer.

Query time is a poor performance measurement on a server with high load because any query may be slow on a busy server. You should use EXPLAIN and SHOW PROFILE to profile your queries and improve them so that they do not put too much load on your server.

Use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` when profiling queries so the results are not stored in the query cache, otherwise subsequent executions of the same query may use the query cache, skewing any timing of the query.

Comment: regarding cache: when I ran the query manually(still on the server, not locally, on same DB) I changed order of some of the conditions, so it won't be able to match the result to the previously ran query.

I've ran explain and it does show it uses some indexes, but I'm really not sure if they are correct. in the "possible indexes" list there were many other indexes that weren't used.

Comment: also I've noticed that the number of scanned rows greatly exceeds the number of rows actually fetched. in fact the statement itself has LIMIT 50 on it, and rows scanned is around 3000. 

my thoughts were that it's due to the ORDER BY in the statement, which to my understanding fetchs all rows(even though there's LIMIT on the query) and only after the order by it returns 50. is this correct?

Comment: @MikiBergin, If the ORDER BY clause can be served by the index, then it won't necessarily have to fetch all the rows. There are some caveats, but it's too much to discuss here. I recommend that if you need help optimizing a specific query, please post a separate question, complete with the entire query, the relevant schema, and the EXPLAIN and SHOW PROFILE results.

Comment: @MikiBergin, another reason a query can be faster on successive attempts is if your system doesn't have enough RAM to store all of the indexes in memory, so it has to swap indexes into memory from disk. On the second attempt, the index is likely already loaded in memory. Check your memory configuration.